# Getting ready a service in Angular before to be used

Tags: javascript, angular, design-patterns

I'm pretty new in Angular. I don't know if this pattern that I'm using in various services is correct. 
My service needs do some http requests in order to be ready. The constructors can't be async so I solve this problem in this way:

**Service**

```
export class MyService {

    constructor(HttpClient:http) {
    }

    private  longAndNeededMethod():Observable{
       //Blablabla....
       return this.http.post(...);
    }

    async ready() {
      if(notReady){
        await this.longAndNeedMethod().toPromise().then(
          (response)=>{
               //do something
          });
      }
    }

    //Another methods
}
```

**Component**

```
export class MyComponent{
  constructor(private myService:MyService){}

  async onInit(){
    await this.myService.ready();
  }

  //Another methods
}
```

Is this design correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would not lock the UI with await. 
It would be better to have your ready() method return an observable and use that observable to load MyComponent upon completion of the observable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The component shows a spinning wheel while service is loading. The component is nof functional if service is not ready.